# Leaflet.js Is Rotating Big Size Images

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I'm using Leaflet.js for putting markers on floor plans in my web app. But when I upload images that has big sizes (for example 2363*3390) to map control, it rotates image out of my control. When I change rotation of image from windows image viewer anything changes. Why leaflet rotates it automatically ?

```
    function LoadMap(_base64Data, boundHeight, boundWidth) {
        mapLoadCount = mapLoadCount + 1;

        var w = boundWidth,
            h = boundHeight,
            url = '';

        if (mapLoadCount == 1) {
            map = L.map('map', {
                minZoom: 7,
                maxZoom: 18,
                center: [0, 0],
                crs: L.CRS.Simple
            }).setView([50.4333, 30.5167], 16);


            var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
            var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
            bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            overlay = L.imageOverlay(url, bounds);
            overlay.addTo(map);

            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

            markerLayer = new L.FeatureGroup();
            deletedMarkers = new L.FeatureGroup();
            map.addLayer(markerLayer);
        }
        else {
            var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
            var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
            bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            map.removeLayer(overlay);

            overlay = L.imageOverlay(_base64Data, bounds);
            overlay.addTo(map);

            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, but after a lot search, i rather to use `L.imageTransform(image_object, latlngs ).addTo(map);` instead of using `L.imageOverlay()` 
i rewrite your code with above change. it's functionally work for me, i many project. just check your code and parameter if you do not get good result.
I set the "image_latlngs" not to be squre, you can change the parameter to build your wanted shape.

```
function LoadMap(_base64Data, boundHeight, boundWidth) {
    mapLoadCount = mapLoadCount + 1;

    var w = boundWidth,
        h = boundHeight,
        url = '';

    if (mapLoadCount == 1) {
        map = L.map('map', {
            minZoom: 7,
            maxZoom: 18,
            center: [0, 0],
            crs: L.CRS.Simple
        }).setView([50.4333, 30.5167], 16);


        // var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
        // var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
        // bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

        // overlay = L.imageOverlay(url, bounds);
        // overlay.addTo(map);


        // ######### new codes #############
        var latlng = map.getBounds().getCenter();
        var X = latlng.lat;
        var Y = latlng.lng;
        var delta = Math.pow(2,map.getMaxZoom() - map.getZoom())*0.000000001;
        var image_latlngs = [
            [X + delta , Y - delta],
            [X + delta * 3/2 , Y + delta * 3/2 ],
            [X + delta * 1/2 , Y +  + delta * 5/2  ],
            [X - delta * 1/2 , Y - delta * 1/2]
        ];
        var image = L.imageTransform( url , image_latlngs ).addTo(map);
        map.setMaxBounds(map.getBounds());
        // ######### new codes #############



        markerLayer = new L.FeatureGroup();
        deletedMarkers = new L.FeatureGroup();
        map.addLayer(markerLayer);
    }
    else {
        // var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
        // var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
        // bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

        // map.removeLayer(overlay);
        // overlay = L.imageOverlay(_base64Data, bounds);
        // overlay.addTo(map);

        // ######### new codes #############
        map.removeLayer(image);
        var latlng = map.getBounds().getCenter();
        var X = latlng.lat;
        var Y = latlng.lng;
        var delta = Math.pow(2,map.getMaxZoom() - map.getZoom())*0.000000001;
        var image_latlngs = [
            [X + delta , Y - delta],
            [X + delta * 3/2 , Y + delta * 3/2 ],
            [X + delta * 1/2 , Y +  + delta * 5/2  ],
            [X - delta * 1/2 , Y - delta * 1/2]
        ];
        var image = L.imageTransform( url , image_latlngs ).addTo(map);
        map.setMaxBounds(map.getBounds());
        // ######### new codes #############
    }
}
```

Comment: My main problem was I don't know which size images users will upload. The image can be vertical or horizontal. If I don't set bounds by image size , map container is strecthing. Because of this I'm sending image height and width via parameter. So in your code you getBounds() from map. Then calculating image_latlngs by this bounds. How can I calculate this from my image sizes ?

Comment: on my above code size of image is not important. when ever user pick a image, on any size. it would be set on the map on the scale of map Bounds. but some other details please.tell me more about what you want.